# Find files in website directory

Tags: web, directory

Let's say there's a website `www.example.com/user/john`. Accessing that link takes you to `www.example.com/user/john/index.html`.

There are files like `www.example.com/user/john/picture.png` and `www.example.com/user/john/document.html`. These are also accessible to the public, but there's no link to these from `index.html`.

Is there a systematic way to find out these files? I'm asking because I'm going to set up my website, and I also want to put up a few files that I don't necessarily want every one to see, only people who I give the link to. So I'm wondering how easy/hard it is to find out that those files exist in my directory.

Comment: If there's no reference to those files anywhere then somebody would have to guess the file name.  This is easy if there's a pattern to the names, of course.  In general this is called "security through obscurity."  It doesn't actually prevent unauthorized access to those files, it just requires that somebody needs to know the files are there in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly you have to switch off the possibility to just browse the directory with the browser. Every server has its own way to switch this off. Then you can use the proposed way of "security through obscurity".

Another way can be, to have a specific folder whos access is restricted by a http basic authentication. This can be configured in the .htaccess file which you put in the root folder of your directory you want to share only with specific people.

Just google ".htacces" and "basic authentication".

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not provide a directory listing method as such. Most web servers can be set up to provide a HTML-formatted directory listing if an index file such as index.html does not exist. If you provide an index file so that autoindexing does not happen (or if you disable autoindex by web server configuration), *and* if your "hidden" file names are hard to guess, they should be pretty hard to find. I sometimes publish such files in a directory with a random gibberish name.

"Share links" used by Dropbox, Picasa and other services do the same, they just use longer random file/directory names or random parameters in the URL.

To provide real security you'll want to set up https (SSL/TLS) so that any eavesdroppers on the network cannot easily look at the requested URLs, and authentication such as HTTP Basic Authentication with username/password. For less sensitive stuff, http to a random hidden directory will often do fine.